# Can aromaticity arise from 3c-2e bonds

Tags: aromatic-compounds, bent-bond

Electrons are delocalized between the three centers in a  3c-2e bond. If there was a molecule with 3c-2e bond in each direction, e.g. a boron cluster, would it be aromatic?

Comment: related: http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2014/OB/C4OB01018C#!divAbstract

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cyclopropenyl (1) cation is believed to be aromatic as it demonstrates abnormal stability and NMR-shifts typical for aromatic compounds. Moreover, there are a good number of derived systems, where aromatic conjugation is maintained despite extra methylene insertions into the ring, such as is typical for the nornbornadienyl (2) cation. Some of these cations can be isolated in salts or observed via NMR in solution. Signs of aromaticity are found also for the cyclooctatetraene dianion and the cyclononatetraene dianion, both produced by reduction of the corresponding alkene with metallic sodium. Remember, please, that even though all systems noted above are 'aromatic' in some sense and are abnormally stable for their family of species, they are still very reactive, because they all belong to a very reactive family of species. While the neutral boron analog of the cyclopropenyl cation has not been isolated to my knowledege, a similar structure was found in [organometalic compounds](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.201402815/abstract). Aromaticity of some ring systems may result in some weird properties of some compounds, like squaric acid (abnormally strong for ketoenol and a stable enol), high polarity and basicity of cyclononatrienol and cyclopropenone and so on.

(1) - cyclopropenyl cation

[image: cyclopropenyl cation]

(2) nornbornadienyl cation

[image: nornbornadienyl cation]

Comment: Good to know, but this still doesn't give an answer to my question.

Comment: Than please elaborate. You see, the only thing needed for aromaticity is to have 4n+2 electrons in conjugated pi-system in a ring. That's all. How orbitals and electrons are provided is irrelevant from theoretical point of view, though it does affect reactivity of the particle. I... don't understand what is hard to understand here.

Comment: That's according to the Huckel rule, but what about Mobius aromaticity? I thought here about some exotic type of aromaticity.

Comment: Hm. Well, there are rules for stability of metallic cluster particles and rules for extra stability of boron-based clusters. For example, $\ce{B12H12^{2-}}$ is a fully delocalized structure with all $\ce{B-B}$ distances equal. $\ce{B12}$ unit is extremely common in reduced boron chemistry. However, they are not widely recognized as 'aromatic' as they are not as widespread, and do not have so long history, this is a bit of esoteric knowledge of those involved in their respective field.

Comment: Could you list some of the rules?

Comment: @Marko http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_skeletal_electron_pair_theory

Comment: A complex with a borirene functioning as an aromatic ployhapto logand is known.  See [here](http://sro.sussex.ac.uk/id/eprint/47846/).  Supporting information contained in the link shows the structure of the borirene and its complex.

Answer (score 1):

We may consider the pi electrons of the cyclopropenyl cation as a 3c-2e bond.  An even better example of a 3c-2e bond producing aromaticity is the trihydrogen cation, in which three protons are bound into a triangle with two electrons.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trihydrogen_cation).